# which domain extension should i choose to be country specific

Tags: web-hosting, domain-name

hi i am in the US but would like to help develop a website for a friend located in Singapore. He wanted the target audience of the website to be local (Singapore). i am confused as to whether i should go with .sg or .com when registering for a domain name.

is it advisable for me to register ".com" domain and use meta tags and google webmaster tools to be country specific/ should i just register for a ".sg" domain?

PS: i am planning to register with goDaddy and use their web hosting service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is off-topic for StackOverflow and belongs on a different StackExchange site. I'm not sure where it belongs, but it certainly doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with '.com' as it is widely used and known to be somewhat universal, rather than country specific, (meaning you can't go wrong).

If you're planning on hosting with GoDaddy, make sure to choose a server-region that would be advantageous to visitors in Singapore.  This will help to optimize loading times for people in that region.

In addition you can try to manually optimize the site for Singapore by choosing country specific page content and meta tags, build incoming/outgoing links to other (SG) relates sites etc.